# How to position the button to be in line with the title?

Tags: html, css

my title isn't aligned with the gear button on the same row.

```
<div id="header">
 <button href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-gear ui-btn-icon-notext" id="setting"></button>
    <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
```

This is the link to the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bxaU5/13/)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 things here to style.

- Set a `float:left` for your button
- set a `margin-top:0px` for your `h1`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/bxaU5/15/)**

```
#setting{
    float:left;
}
h1{
    margin-top:0px;
}
```